# How to remove square brackets from the output of KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

In the following code the output returns

```
[Text1, Text2]
```

I want the output not to have *square brackets*:

```
 Text1, Text2
```

How can I solve this issue? (This is a simple example and I will use it in my own project)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     KeyValuePair<string, string> my_pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Text1", "Text2");

     Console.WriteLine(my_pair);
     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{my_pair.Key}, {my_pair.Value}");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

```
Console.WriteLine(my_pair);
```

calls `ToString()` for `my_pair` and prints out the computed string. If you want some kind of custom format you can do it with a help of *string interpolation*:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{my_pair.Key}, {my_pair.Value}");
```

Here .net will compute each expression within `{...}` and put the results into the string

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(my_pair);
```

Calls the function ToString() on the KeyValuePair which according to [Microsoft.Net Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com), does the following.

```
public override string ToString() {
    StringBuilder s = StringBuilderCache.Acquire();
    s.Append('[');
    if( Key != null) {
        s.Append(Key.ToString());
    }
    s.Append(", ");
    if( Value != null) {
       s.Append(Value.ToString());
    }
    s.Append(']');
    return StringBuilderCache.GetStringAndRelease(s);
}
```

As you can see, the KeyValuePair.ToString() method surrounds the key and value with square brackets.

In order to output the KeyValuePair in your preferred format, you could do the following.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1}", my_pair.Key, my_pair.Value));
```